# how to get intervals from a range

Tags: php, intervals

With algorithm how can I remove intervals within a range in php:

Example 1:

range: [8-22]

input:

> interval: [11,13]
> interval: [16,18]

output:

> [8,10] , [14,15], [19,22]

Example 2:

range: [8-22]

input:

> interval: [8,11]
> interval: [16,18]

output:

> [12,15], [19,22]

thanks

Comment: Please format the code and use a capital letter when starting a sentence.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution

```
$array = range(8, 22);
$newarray = array_diff($array, range(11, 13))
```

thanks